# Вставка картинки в текст

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно вставлять картинки за место слов в тексте в `RichTextBox`, соответственно что бы обтекание было слева и справа.

Использую сейчас что-то подобное

```
string[] messageSplit = message.Split(' ');
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

for (int i = 0; i < messageSplit.Length; ++i) {
            string str = messageSplit[i];
            if (str.Contains("${emoteId=")) {

                string id = ...
                Image image = new Image();
                image.Source = (ImageSource)((new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFromString($@"emotes/{id}.png"));

                BlockUIContainer cont = new BlockUIContainer(image);
                Figure figure = new Figure(cont);
                figure.Width = (new FigureLength(24));
                figure.WrapDirection = WrapDirection.Both;
                figure.VerticalAnchor = FigureVerticalAnchor.PageTop;
                figure.HorizontalAnchor = FigureHorizontalAnchor.PageLeft;

                paragraph.Inlines.Add(figure);
            } else {
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(str));
            }
        doc.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        MessageText.Document = doc;
```

Но при такой вставке весь текст что был переносится на верх, а все картинки появляются внизу.

Как сделать правильную вставку в текст?

Сам текст имеет такой вид `qqq ${emoteId=4} www ${emoteId=5} ${emoteId=20} eee`

Comment: Может наоборот текст на картинку? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] messageSplit = message.Split(' ');
            FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

            for (int i = 0; i < messageSplit.Length; ++i) {
                string str = messageSplit[i];
                if (str.Contains("${emoteId=")) {
                    string id = ...


                    Image image = new Image();
                    image.Source = (ImageSource)((new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFromString($@"emotes/{id}.png"));
                    image.Width = 28;

                    InlineUIContainer inlineUIContainer = new InlineUIContainer(image);
                    paragraph.Inlines.Add(inlineUIContainer);
                    paragraph.Inlines.Add(" ");
                } else {
                    paragraph.Inlines.Add(str + " ");
                }
            }

            doc.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
            MessageText.Document = doc;
```